# Shiny Server host static markdown output, display directory

Tags: r-markdown, shiny-server

This is two separate questions that I am asking together because I think they might be related to each other.

First, is it possible to get shiny server to host .html files? specifically the output of rmarkdown. I would like to host a combination of static markdown results and interactive markdown. I know this can be done because of the special index.html file, which works just fine. However if I try any other .html file I get **Not Found**. (eg: :3838/Project/example.html)

For the static file, I can host the .Rmd file with no issues, but it is compiled new every time I visit it, and in this case it has about a 5 minute runtime. I would like to run it once and host the results. (yes, I could run the time consuming code separately and save those results as an rdata file to be loaded but that seems like a sub optimal solution)

The second issue is when I open a directory (:3838/Project/) and there is no index.html file in it I get **Not Found** rather than the directory of applications.

here is my shiny-server.conf file. (I have set shiny up to run in a home directory owned by shiny and the shinyusr group rather than in the default srv directory)

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    #site_dir /srv/shiny-server;
    site_dir /home/shiny/apps;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    #log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
    log_dir /home/shiny/logs;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```